# User authentication libraries for web & mobile?

Tags: authentication, user-accounts

When building an MVP quickly, I've found it useful to use existing 3rd-party libraries, such as Parse, Stripe, Filepicker.io, Mixpanel, etc.

Does such a library exist for user authentication? Such as login forms, forgot password forms, etc. Ideally, this would work across platforms so it can be used on web and native mobile apps.